# Can I use oauth 2.0 with flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, oauth-2.0

I want my flex mobile app to connect to the Google services, specifically the new Google Drive, to upload and download files. Is this possible using AS3 and Flash Builder? I believe oauth 2.0 is required for authenication. Can this be done with Action Script? I've looked around and only found oauth v1 libraries. Also, are there any APIs working with Google Drive that works with Flash Builder?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you are still interested with the Google Drive API, but i've just released a (REALLY) beta version of that. You can check here: http://code.google.com/p/google-drive-as3-api-client/ . 
See the example in Wiki section and refer to the full example (for Flex) that you can find here: http://code.google.com/p/google-drive-as3-api-client/source/browse/trunk/src/AS3GoogleDriveAPI.mxml

Bye

Comment: That looks really useful! I'll try it out. Keep up the good work=)

Comment: Andrea - I have been writing my own OAuth library that in theory can be used in Web Based Flex apps, Air apps and mobile. Air and Mobile work great but for the web applications I keep running into Security errors when trying to access http://accounts.google.com. Did you have any similar issues? How did you get over them? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

yes

> Actionscript 3 library for oAuth client implementations, for use in Flash, Flex and AIR.

http://code.google.com/p/oauth-as3/