# Google Drive AS3 API for web environment

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, google-drive-api

I'm working on an application using Flex 4.x and AS3 which could show the videos from one's Google Drive. For this I need to use OAuth so that I can connect to Drive with my username and password. But, it seems Google hasn't provided an API for AS3 to make applications which can access the Drive. I saw an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357797/can-i-use-oauth-2-0-with-flex?answertab=active#tab-top) but the API provided is for a standalone, window based application. Could anyone please provide an isight into what are the options available? [I tried commenting in that question itself, but it seems I cant comment without much points.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your application will be embedded into web page, the anwser is a use of javascript to make OAuth call. After that you can use google drive api from actionscript, using as3 api.
This approach will let you skip authentication if user already logged onto google drive.

Good illustration how it works without actionsript can be found here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#try-it

Comment: But, is there an API for Goodle Drive targeting AS3 available. I looked for one, but couldn't find Google's own version and the other one available seems to target Windowed applications.

Comment: I guess api realization for as3 available here http://code.google.com/p/google-drive-as3-api-client/
it was only OAuth2 there, which used AIR only component
you can move OAuth2 call to javascript and continue using API from flash

Comment: i took a look at http://code.google.com/p/oauth-as3 it doesn't seems using any AIR dependant components, but anyway i advise to use javascript call, just because of using existing session cookies

Comment: Roman: Thank you for the clarification. I looked at Oauth 3 implementation but the reason why I backed out was I couldn't see any wiki items in that project. I guess, I'll checkout the code and then work on it to find if it could be directly be employed. I'm not that comfortable with Javascript.